# Emacs: Emacs Live Freezing issue

Tags: emacs

I have been using Emacs -live installed from [here](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live). The problem that keeps showing up and bothering me is that Emacs occasionally freezes when I am coding. It just froze for 15 seconds and then resumed and became normal again. And this is happening more frequently now than before.

My friends also face the same problem. Does anyone know what might be causing this problem ? And how can we overcome it ?

Comment: You'll likely have much better luck if you use regular GNU Emacs instead of some third-party distribution. As it stands, this question is far too broad and lacks the detail required to answer it.

Comment: Emacs-live is like a package that you installed into the regular Emacs. It's not like AquaMacs.

Comment: Did you try opening a Github ticket? Are there any similar issues reported on their issue tracker?

Comment: One thing you could try is typing `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` when you start Emacs, and when it freezes again hit `C-g`. This _might_ give you a `*Backtrace*` buffer that should give more information about the problem.